# PHP build an array of an unknown size using date variables

Tags: php

I'm struggling with how to build the following:

result I need:

```
$months = array();
$months
(
    month[0] = '2011-10-1'
    month[1] = '2011-11-1'
    month[2] = '2011-12-1'
    month[3] = '2012-1-1'
)
```

from the following variables:

```
$date = '2011-10-1';
$numberOfMonths = 4;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, guys... all of these solutions work.  I accepted the one that works best for my usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function getNextMonths($date, $numberOfMonths){
    $timestamp_now = strtotime($date);
    $months[] = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp_now);
    for($i = 1;$i <= $numberOfMonths; $i++){
          $months[] = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime($months[0].' +'.$i.' month')));
    }
    print_r($months);
}
getNextMonths('2011-10-1', 4);
```

[Working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/986fe/9)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a simple loop and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = '2011-10-1';
$numberOfMonths = 4; 

$current = strtotime($date);
$months = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfMonths; $i++) {
  $months[$i] = date('Y-n-j', $current);
  $current = strtotime('+1 month', $current);
}
```

Comment: @nachito: Good lord it's been a long week! Thanks for pointing that out, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j', '2011-10-1');

$months = array();
for ($m = 0; $m < $numberOfMonths; $m++) {
   $next = $date->add(new DateInterval("P{$m}M"));
   $months[] = $next->format('Y-m-j');
}
```

Comment: Good solution for PHP >= 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` on `date` and then a `for` loop over the month. The trick is to use something like

```
$newMonth = ($month + $i) % 12 + 1;
```

(`%` is called modulo and does exactly what you want.)

Comment: This does not take care of the next year?

Comment: No, but you can just increment the year when `$month == 1`